# Linear transformation $T(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=(0,X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}) $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-fields

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $F^n\to F^n$ defined by:
$$T(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=(0,X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}) $$

I need to calculate $T^k$ for every $k\in N$ and to find the matrix represents $T$.

I have no idea how I should start to think about the solution.
Any help is welcome. thanks.

Comment: Think of the transformation as shifting all of the coordinates to the right one slot and shifting a zero in from the left.

Comment: Wouldn't this be just the Jordan-block of size n and $\lambda=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that $$T^2(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=T (0,X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}) = (0,0,X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-2})$$

so $$T^k(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=0$$ whenever $k\ge n$

the matrix rep will have $T_{ij}=1$ when $j=i+1$ and  $T_{ij}=0$ otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Computing $T^2$: just apply $T$ twice.
$$T^2(X_1,\ldots, X_n)=T(0,X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_{n-1}) = (0,0,X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_{n-2}).$$
Can you see the pattern for $T^k$? What happens when $k \ge n$?

---

You want to find a matrix $A$ such that
$$A \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots\\ X_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Just handle it one row of $A$ at a time. For example, the second row of $A$ satisfies $a_{21} X_1 + a_{22} X_2 + \cdots + a_{2n} X_n = X_1$, so the second row is $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$.

A different way to think about this is as follows. If we apply $A$ to a standard unit vector $e_j$, we get the $j$th column of $A$. If we want $A e_j = T(e_j)$, this implies $T(e_j)$ is the $j$th column of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is shifting operator.
Whenever you apply it to a set of n elements it shifts them by 1 position and make the first position as 0, now if you apply it again (i.e.you have applied $T^2$) you will get shifts them by 1 position and make the first position as $0$.

T
    2
  
  (
  
    X
    1
  
  ,
  
    X
    2
  
  ,
  .
  .
  .
  ,
  
    X
    n
  
  )
  =
  T
  (
  0
  ,
  
    X
    1
  
  ,
  
    X
    2
  
  ,
  .
  .
  .
  ,
  
    X
    
      n
      −
      1
    
  
  )
  =
  (
  0
  ,
  0
  ,
  
    X
    1
  
  ,
  
    X
    2
  
  ,
  .
  .
  .
  ,
  
    X
    
      n
      −
      2
    
  
  )

Thus, proceeding in similar manner you will get  $T^k$ =$0$ for all k$\ge n$

Answer (score 0):

$T$ just shifts coordinates to the right. So $T^k(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (0,\ldots,0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-k})$ (you can check this by induction to be very formal).

On standard basis elements, we have $T(e_i) = e_{i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $T(e_n) = 0$, so we find that the matrix representation is the identity matrix where each $1$ on the diagonal has been shifted downwards. In other words, it is zero everywhere except on the subdiagonal, where it is populated with $1$s.